# How to fetch the closest attribute in this case?

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/ftjaybnm/1/

When the user clicks on a collapsible div an 'Add more' button is shown. On cliik of that button how can I fetch a data attribute of it?

```
$(document).on('click', '.addmore', function(event) {
    var dataclciked = $(this).closest('.data').attr('data_city');
    alert(dataclciked);
});
```

Could you please tell me how to fetch the attribute of the collapsible div?

Comment: Try `var dataclciked = $(this).closest('.data > div').attr('data_city');` (http://jsfiddle.net/ftjaybnm/2/).

Comment: Your Fiddle is messy, take a source code, not JQM generated. Your html5 data attributes are wrong, you need to follow the convention, than you can access it with `elem.data()`.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly all your `data` attributes are incorrect. They should be `data-*`, not `data_*`. Also, the `city` data attribute is on the closest `.my-collapsible` element, so the logic is incorrect. Finally you can use the `data()` method to retrieve the information:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addmore', function (event) {
    var dataclicked = $(this).closest('.my-collaspible').data('city');
    alert(dataclicked);
});
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ftjaybnm/4/)

If, for whatever reason, you cannot change the invalid `data_` attributes (although you *really really* should), you can read them using `attr()`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addmore', function (event) {
    var dataclicked = $(this).closest('.my-collaspible').attr('data_city');
    alert(dataclicked);
});
```

Comment: `data_*` ya, that's the most shocking part ;)

Comment: @Kiran `data_attr` is not valid. You *will* have to change them.

Comment: There is a attribute named data_city on the colapsable that i need to read .

Comment: I've updated my answer for you, but again, you *REALLY* should change the data attributes to follow valid syntax

Comment: If you are a part of a team, than you cannot change other code easily.

Comment: @skobaljic I would argue that if you're part of a team you should advise people when they're writing bad code.

Comment: Yes, but you simply cannot change it. Those guys may be in other country, than they need to change it, than they need approval, than to update the code... it may last for weeks.

Comment: If it takes weeks to get approval to change a data attribute then there are bigger issues in project management. I know the point your going for, and I agree on large adjustments in logic, however this is about fixing code that is plainly wrong and needs to be changed ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

First change the `data_city` to `data-city`. then you can get it like this:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.addmore', function(event) {      
         var dataclciked = $(this).closest('div').data('city');
        alert(dataclciked);
   });
```

Other wise:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.addmore', function(event) {      
         var dataclciked = $(this).closest('div').attr('data_city');
        alert(dataclciked);
   });
```